# Pod self delete

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

In my environment, I have one service which generates `yml` with the necessary configurations so the file can be executed with `kubectl apply` to create a pod.
My question is: can I generate a `yml` file with instructions so the pod can delete itself when the status is completed(`status.phase==Succeeded` )?

Currently, I'm solving this issue with [cronjobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/). Also, I know that I could use something like `kubectl delete pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded --namespace <namespace>` but I want to know if it can be done through the configuration file of the pod(`yml`).

This is the file generated by the service(builder) to be executed with the `kubectl apply -f <yml file>`:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: order-test
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: order-test
        image: namespace/image:version
        env:
          - name: example
            value: "test"
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

And I want to automatically delete it, after it reaches the desired status.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Jobs History Limits**
*The `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` fields are optional. These fields specify how many completed and failed jobs should be kept. By default, they are set to 3 and 1 respectively. Setting a limit to 0 corresponds to keeping none of the corresponding kind of jobs after they finish.*

Ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits

Comment: as you can see, in my `yml` file, there are 2 `spec` objects. I tried to set `successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0` inside both of them but it didn't work. Could you edit your answer structuring the `yml` file setting this field in?

Comment: as my research suggests, this field `failedJobsHistoryLimit` is only available in a `CronJob` file, not in my case, which the `kind` is `Job`.